# PrimeVue datatable components not working in vue3

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs3, primevue

I'm using PrimeVue fatatable for my website, but even though I've installed all requirements nothing shows up for me. there's only a warning coming up:

```
Failed to resolve component: data-table
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

in main.js

```
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import Column from 'primevue/column'
import Dialog from 'primevue/dialog'
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable'
appInstance.use(PrimeVue)
appInstance.component('Column', Column)
appInstance.component('Dialog', Dialog)
appInstance.component('Datatable', DataTable)
```

in userTable.vue:

```
<data-table :value="products">
     <Column field="brand" header="Brand"></Column>
     <Column field="year" header="Year"></Column>
     <Column field="color" header="Color"></Column>
     <Column field="vin" header="Vin"></Column>
</data-table>
```

and an example of products in data():

```
products: [
        {"brand": "Volkswagen", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff"},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345"},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr"},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh"},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34"},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj"},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr"},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34"},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5"},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s"}
      ],
```

It's vue 3 I'm working on, so if anyone knows the reason and solution by anychance, I'll be so glad :')

Comment: In your userTable.vue component, have you tried to call the component with `<datatable></datatable>` instead (without the `-`) ? Because in your main.js you register it as `Datatable` not `DataTable`

Comment: Did it just now, but there's no difference. still nothing is showing

Comment: Currently it's a typo. It should be DataTable and not Datatable. There should be a difference. If it still doesn't work, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are typing the tag wrong
I suggest you change as follows:

```
appInstance.component('Datatable', DataTable)
```

by

```
appInstance.component('DataTable', DataTable)
```

In the component

```
<DataTable :value="products">
     <Column field="brand" header="Brand"></Column>
     <Column field="year" header="Year"></Column>
     <Column field="color" header="Color"></Column>
     <Column field="vin" header="Vin"></Column>
</DataTable>
```